# Where is the location of cached js lib for bower install?

Tags: bower

If I install a js lib with bower install, where is the cached location in my computer?
I am using mac 10.10.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently its located in your home folder.

Following is the exact path to the bower cache

~/.cache/bower/

Comment: In the case of windows?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK %LocalAppData%\bower\cache

Comment: C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Temp\{USER}\bower